# Nolio Error: JSON: Unrecognized field "artifactVersions"

Tags: mysql, json, linux, nolio

In version 5.0, when attempting to change the Server Type property of an
existing Artifact Definition, the following error occurs:

Unexpected exception caught on server. Exception type is
[HttpMessageNotReadableException], exception message is [Could not read
JSON: Unrecognized field "artifactVersions" (Class
[...] not marked as ignorable [...]

Steps to recreate:
(1) Created application "Test" in Automation Studio.
(2) Logged into ROC.
(3) Navigated to Artifacts --> Artifact Management.
(4) Added a new Artifact Definition "Test" with "Server Type 1" and
"Server Type 2" selected under Server Types within the Edit Artifact
Definition window.
(5) Clicked Save.
(6) Clicked the Edit Artifact Definition icon.
(7) Unchecked "Server Type 2".
(8) Clicked Save. <-- This is supposedly where the error occurs.

This was encountered with 5.0 installation on a Linux environment, using MySQL as the database.

I cannot recreate the issue in a 5.0 Linux environment running against Oracle 11g, so I'm suspicious of it being a database-specific issue or just a configuration problem somewhere, but I haven't been able to dig anything up yet.

I have yet find any errors in various logs that cite the JSON error above either, so I'm a bit at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that a clean installation or upgraded from previous versions? If it is an upgraded installation this might be a browser caching problem.